# Setting a (string) variable equal to another (string) variable including modifications

Tags: powershell, local-variables, powershell-module

I'm trying to get better at *reusable* PowerShell (v5.1, but v-agnostic) scripting at scale with libraries, and I have a very simple task I'll use for illustration. Coming from C# the pseudocode to create a variable from another, with some changes would look something like

```
string somevar = "foo";
string someothervar = DoSomethingTo(somevar); // lots of variations HERE
Debug.Print someothervar;
```

Let's say it's a simple `replace` operation. I won't bother writing that in C# (or PoSh) but since it's fundamentally a scripting language, every blog- or documentation-type example I can find for `replace` looks something like

```
> $somevar = "foo"
> {# here are 3 ways to say replace in PowerShell}
> # here is some console output of what happens when you do that
```

I do not care about console output. I care about understanding **all** the *PowerShell-native* ways I can make a `$someothervar` out of operation(s) on `$somevar`, e.g. replacing some part of it. (I know I can essentially invoke .NET.)

If I were to ask this question in an even worse way, it would be something like "how do you set local PowerShell variables in inline operations using other PowerShell variables and/or parameters".

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing your question? Having a hard time understanding what you want. Are you looking for a deeper dive explanation on how Powershell variables work?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I *did* work on the phrasing, believe it or not, for quite a while before, and then while, posting here. (I think the body itself says so.) BUT I agree, it still sucks. It's probably a PoSh noob fail, and probably won't help anyone. 

Setting a variable using a series of chained operations in C# is really simple. Setting it as if .NET didn't exist in PoSh is harder (at least for me, so far). Sorry I can't help more, would love to be more explicit and narrow.

Comment: I'm still confused why you think you can't do that in PowerShell. It doesn't matter how many things you chain together whatever is output from those expressions will get captured by the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell any output can be assigned to a variable.  If it isn't assigned or otherwise consumed it will output to the host, usually the console.

Your example derived from pseudo code might be something like:

```
$SomeOtherVar = $SomeVar -replace "one", "two"
```

The same would be true if you invoked a .Net method on the string:

```
$SomeOtherVar = $SomeVar.Replace( "one", "two" )
```

Also important is assigning the output of a command which can be a cmdlet, function or even a command line executable.

Note: that calling functions & cmdlets is a little different in PowerShell.  Don't specify arguments parenthetically. Separate parameters and arguments with spaces and/or use the named parameters.

```
$SomeOtherVar = Get-SomeData $SomeVar

$SomeOtherVar = Ping $SomeVar
```

The summary answer to your question is anything PowerShell outputs can be assigned to a variable. So, literally anything you do to `$SomeVar` that generates output even if the output is null can be assigned to `$SomeOtherVar`

**Responding to Comment / Additional Example:**

```
$SomeVar = 'foo'
$SomeOtherVar = $SomeVar -replace 'foo', 'bar'
$SomeOtherVar
```

Output: `bar`

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, so maybe I'm asking the question wrong? I have e.g. literally tried (both) your first example(s) and `$SomeOtherVar` keeps coming up null.

Comment: I'm nit sure what you mean by "coming up null".

Comment: Sorry, I know comments are not supposed to be follow-ups but still not there (because, again, that is what my code says). I assume there is no difference whether `$SomeVar` is a parameter, a variable, or a literal? What about, say, fancier find/replace like RegEx? (It is perhaps complex inline operations that matter more? I can't identify or I wouldn't have asked.)

Comment: `-replace` takes a RegEx as it's first argument.  The `[RegEx]` .Net class is also accessible. 
 There are certainly differences between variables, parameters & literals.  However, this is a very broad scope, too much to discuss here.  Great bedtime reading recommendation "PowerShell In Action" by Bruce Payette.  It explains much of this.  It may be especially helpful if you are coming from a language like C#.

Comment: Very clear this is not a great question, my apologies, my scope is narrower and my timeline tighter than a full book dive but I appreciate the recommendation and the time you've taken for the needle in the haystack. Will let this marinate a bit longer and accept defeat if nothing else clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

So I find this post somewhat confusing and amusing.  Steven's answer is a good one but seems to not have gotten through somehow so I will try to just throw some code out there and hope something sticks.  If not, at least I tried right?

```
function Append-BarToString {
    param(
        [string]$InputString
    )
    # explicit return keyword not needed.  
    # Any output inside function not assigned  
    # to a variable or to $null will be sent out
    $InputString + "Bar" 
}

# function can also be written without param block 
# more like C# like this, though it is unconventional
function Append-BarToString ([string]$InputString)
{
    # $InputString + "Bar"
    # or 
    "${InputString}Bar"
}

$someVar = 'foo'
$someOtherVar = Append-BarToString $someVar


$someOtherVar
# or
Write-Host $someOtherVar

# output
# fooBar
# fooBar
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice intro to `function` syntax, but I am trying to do it inline/native/public plugin only. We are making progress, even if it is of the blind kind!

Comment: Okay, well, hope you find out what you are looking for anyways.  The reason I went this way with my answer is because of your pseudocode example.  It includes the use of a function to `DoSomethingTo()` your variable.